# How can I use Spatie Media Library with Backpack for Laravel upload field?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to upload a file in Backpack for Laravel and immediately attach the file to the model using Spatie Media Library.

What is my best option to do this?

I tried doing this using the SetImageAttribute mutator as recommended in the docs: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#upload-1

```
public function setImageAttribute($value) {
    $this->addMedia('image');
}
```

However this method requires me to have an unused "image" field on the DB (because Spatie Media Library uses its own table).

Is there another way to do this without using a mutator/creating extra DB fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid having to create an unused **image** field on your DB by overwriting both the **set** and **get** mutators/accessor on your model.

[Laravel documentation defining accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

[Laravel documentation defining mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

Create the following 2 methods on your model:

```php
    public function getImageAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getFirstMediaUrl('image') ?? '';
    }

    public function setImageAttribute($file)
    {
        $this->clearMediaCollection('image'); // to remove any previous files

        if ($file) {
            $this->addMedia($file)->usingFileName($file->hashName())->toMediaCollection('image');
        }
    }
```

If you have a fillable set on your model, also add image to it.

```php
protected $fillable = ['image']
```

Now you should be able to create and update the files using Backpack.
You may change the implementation based on your needs and requirements.